# multiple join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here am having three tables namely `tbl_users`,`tbl_account_details`,`tbl_attendance`.table `tbl_users` looks like this

```
user_id     username            role_id     activated   banned  
    1        admin                  1           1         0         
    36       siraj                  3           1         0     
    37       faizal                 3           1         0     
    38       nesru                  3           1         0     
    40       jaseer                 3           1         0     
    42       maltu                  3           1         0     
    43       shahul                 3           1         0
```

table `tbl_account_details` looks like this

```
account_details_id  user_id     fullname        designations_id     
    1                 1       Administrator         1   
    33                36        siraj               2   
    34                37        faizal              3   
    35                38        nesru               3   
    37                40        jaseer              4   
    39                42        maltu               4   
    40                43        shahul              2
```

my `tbl_attendance` table looks like this

```
attendance_id   user_id      date_in        attendance_status status 0=absent 1=present 3 = onleave 4 = onoff
    1            1          2017-02-05      1
    2            36         2017-02-11      4
    3            36         2017-02-11      4
    4            36         2017-02-11      3
    5            1          2017-02-02      1
    6            36         2017-02-01      1
```

i want to get all `users` where `users` is not in `onleave` and `onoff` on the current day in the `tbl_attendance`.the attendance status for leave is `3` and for off is 4.
in order to get i wrote a query which looks like this

```
public function get_manager_cordinator_users($date)
{

     $this->db->select('tbl_account_details.*', FALSE);
     $this->db->select('tbl_users.*');
     $this->db->join('tbl_account_details', 'tbl_users.user_id = tbl_account_details.user_id', 'left');
     $this->db->where(array('designations_id' => 2));
     $this->db->or_where(array('designations_id' => 3));
     $this->db->where('tbl_users.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE tbl_attendance.date_in='.$date.' && attendance_status=3 OR attendance_status=4 )');
     $query_result = $this->db->get('tbl_users');
     $result = $query_result->result();
     return $result;


}

 my controller looks like this 


$date=date('Y-m-d');
$data['assign_user'] = $this->Project_model->get_manager_cordinator_users($date);
```

please help me to solve...

Comment: which column you need from `tbl_account_details`?and why?

Comment: `designations_id` in order to get all users where `designations_id` is 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

I've created query which will return the data of users with designation_id 2 and 3, also which don't have attendance_status 3 and 4

Your controller code is fine -

```php
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$data['assign_user'] = $this->Project_model->get_manager_cordinator_users($date);
```

Just change your model code with below one -

```php
public function get_manager_cordinator_users($date)
{
  $this->db->select( 'tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.username,tbl_account_details.designations_id, tbl_attendance.date_in, tbl_attendance.attendance_status' );
  $this->db->from( 'tbl_users' );
  $this->db->join( 'tbl_account_details', 'tbl_account_details.user_id = tbl_users.user_id' );
  $this->db->join( 'tbl_attendance', 'tbl_attendance.user_id = tbl_users.user_id' );
  $this->db->where( 'tbl_attendance.date_in', $date );
  $this->db->where('tbl_users.banned', 0);
  $this->db->where('tbl_users.activated', 1);
  $this->db->where_in( 'tbl_account_details.designations_id', array( '2', '3' ) );
  $this->db->where_not_in( 'tbl_attendance.attendance_status', array( '3', '4' ) );
  return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

It will provide you required user data.

Comment: i need to get all users where not in `tbl_attendance.date_in` not like $this->db->where( 'tbl_attendance.date_in', $date );

Comment: i want the query which will return the data of users with designation_id 2 and 3, also which don't have attendance_status 3 and 4 on the current date

Comment: here output will come only if the current date is in  `tbl_attendance`.

Comment: @user_777 I guess you should save date of attendance on every entry. That would be a logical thing and will also help you in fulfilling your requirement.

Comment: Do you save each user's attendance every day ?

Comment: no thats why am going in this way `$this->db->where('tbl_users.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE tbl_attendance.date_in= "'.$date.'" AND tbl_attendance.attendance_status=3 OR tbl_attendance.attendance_status=4)');`

Comment: if the current date attendance_status=3 or 4 then that user should not be get thats the logic where i want to use

Comment: Ok but for that you need the date to be saved in attendance table. Then above query will return the users which were not on leave or off for the particular date.

Answer (score 0):

now i got it

```
public function get_manager_cordinator_users()
{
 $date=date('Y-m-d');
 $this->db->select('tbl_users.*');
 $this->db->join('tbl_account_details', 'tbl_users.user_id = tbl_account_details.user_id', 'left');
 $this->db->where('tbl_users.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE tbl_attendance.date_in= "'.$date.'" AND tbl_attendance.attendance_status IN (3,4) ) ');

 $this->db->where_in( 'tbl_account_details.designations_id', array( '2','3' ) );
 $this->db->where('tbl_users.banned', 0);
 $this->db->where('tbl_users.activated', 1);

 $query_result = $this->db->get('tbl_users');
 $result = $query_result->result();
 return $result;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
     $this->db->select('tbl_account_details.*', FALSE);
     $this->db->select('tbl_users.*');
     $this->db->join('tbl_users', 'tbl_users.user_id = tbl_account_details.user_id', 'left');
     $this->db->where('(designations_id=2 or designations_id=3 )');
     $this->db->where('tbl_users.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE tbl_attendance.date_in='.$date.' && attendance_status=3 OR attendance_status=4 )');
     $query_result = $this->db->get('tbl_users');
     $result = $query_result->result();
     return $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

$this->db->select('*)->from('tbl_users')->where('tbl_attendance.attendance_status <= 2')->where('tbl_attendance.data_in =',date('Y-m-d'))->join('tbl_attendance','tbl_attendance.user_id = 'tbl_users.user_id ','left')->get()->result();